# Adding Set-Cookie Header to Http Interceptor Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, api, cookies, setcookie

I currently have an angular interceptor that sets some headers. I am aware that on api calls the set-cookie header is created. On my set-cookie header I am missing a secure flag and same-site flag. How would I go about setting those two flags?

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import {
   HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest
} from "@angular/common/http";

import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { timeout } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class AcceptHeadersInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const newRequest = req.clone(
        { setHeaders: { "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json","X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff" ,"X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN" }}
    );
    
    return next.handle(newRequest).pipe(timeout(100000)); //global request timeout after 10s for any api request. Prevent slow http requests. 
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the 500 exception? I bet its Object reference not set to an instance of the object. Breakpoints can help you determine where the actual error is coming from.

Comment: You should set some breakpoints and see how far your getting. If you can't hit the very first line in your POST method (in c#), then check your debugger and see if the link and payload is correct.

Comment: I would also suggest updating your question to only show the relevant parts. You have supplied a lot of code and I don't think it's relevant. They only relevant pieces is the JS code that is executing the POST request and your dotnet method that's supposed to be receiving the request. Everything else is noise.